# Why is EWS search filter returning fewer emails than I see from outlook?

Tags: email, outlook, exchangewebservices

I am using the following code to retrieve emails whose subject contains "MS" and "QW". I see more than 8 emails satisfying the search criteria, but the code returns only two emails. Can anyone help me take a look at what the problem is in here?

```
     var filter1 = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, "MS", ContainmentMode.Substring, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCase);
     var filter2 = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, "QW");
     var sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, filter1, filter2);
     var findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf view);
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things I can see if with the Second search filter you haven't specified the ContainmentMode or ComparsisonMode. You also don't seem to have added them to the SearchFilter Collection. eg you should have

sf.Add(filter1);
sf.Add(filter2);

That Search will yield pretty poor performance on a folder with a large number I would suggest you maybe look at AQS then you can do

service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "Subject:MS AND Subject:QW" ,view);

That will search against the Content Indexes and yield better performance.

Comment: I edited the post to add filter1 and filter2 to the collection. That is a typo in the post and thanks for pointing it out. However, the problem I originally described is till present.

Comment: You still haven't fixed filter2 you missing ContainmentMode eg if you don't define it your not going to get a consistent experience.  Also if you going to ignore the case why use uppercase letters. Your going to need to try different combinations to work your issue out (eg did you try AQS)